# Bean scope is generating java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: spring, scope

I have multi module maven project,which has one common module which is being used by other modules. In common module I have few beans(Beans are having singleton scope) that are used by other modules application context. Now the problem is having after using those beans in one module(m1) which was not previously using these beans. Importing the common.xml(Beans are defined here) in Application context of module(m1) generates lot of issue(Cannot find the beans). So I decided to directly use those beans in application context of module(m1). If I keep the scope of beans to singelton , I get  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jzmq in java.library.path. This issue is solved by using prototype as scope.

Any idea about this issue.

Comment: Common module and other modules which are using beans are normal modules which are deployed using JAR and other module in which I want to use the bean is web module deployed using war in tomcat. It could be issue?

Answer (score 0):

**1** Using native methods make your Java application code platform dependent.

**2** The System.loadLibrary method is equivalent as executing the Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary method.

**3** The System.loadLibrary method shall be used in a static initializer block, in order to be loaded only once, when the JVM loads the class for the first time.

Comment: Reference purpose check the Link: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-how-to-handle-unsatisfied-link-error/

Comment: Thanks Arjun, But I am not able to understand why my code works with prototype and not with singleton. I cannot change the scope as it breaks the other code pieces.